# MySQL - ORDER result based on how many ORs it match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-like

databases are not my strength and I'm not sure if what I look for even exist. In general I would be happy for any advise which can lead me the right way.

#### What I've got:

I've got a query with multiple OR imagine it like something bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' OR video.name LIKE '%%audi%';
```

Let's imagine result for this query gonna be:

```
+------------+---------------+
| id | name                  |
+------------+---------------+
|  1 | My best audi          |
|  2 | topspeed of mustang?  |
|  3 | audi A7 topspeed      |
|  4 | Do you like audi?     |
|  5 | topspeed of audi Q8   |
+------------+---------------+
```

#### What I need:

Is there a way to ORDER results based on how many ORs it match?
So in other words I would expect the order from original example would be:

```
+------------+---------------+
| id | name                  |
+------------+---------------+
|  5 | topspeed of audi Q8   |
|  3 | audi A7 topspeed      |
|  1 | My best audi          |
|  2 | topspeed of mustang?  |
|  4 | Do you like audi?     |
+------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video v
WHERE v.name LIKE '%topspeed%' OR v.name LIKE '%audi%'
ORDER BY (v.name LIKE '%topspeed%') + (v.name LIKE '%audi%') DESC;
```

MySQL treats booleans like numbers in a numeric context, with `1` for "true" and `0` for "false".

Note two other changes.  I added a table alias so the table is easier to reference when qualifying column names.  I also changed `'%%audi'` to `'%audi%'`.  Two `'%'`s in a row doesn't do anything that `'%'` does.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
ORDER BY 
    (video.name LIKE '%topspeed%') + (video.name LIKE '%audi%') DESC,
    id
```

Rationale: in numeric context, a MySQL conditional expression returns `1` if true, else `0`. So videos that match on both conditions get a value of `2`, and those that match on one only get `1`. You can use a descending sort on that. I added another criteria to the `ORDER BY` clause, to get a deterministic sort by breaking the ties.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   id,
   name,
   (CASE WHEN video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN video.name LIKE '%%audi%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as score
FROM video WHERE video.name LIKE '%topspeed%' OR video.name LIKE '%%audi%'
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This query also works on MS-SQL, that's why I use `CASE WHEN....END`.